# Website e banco de dados na mesma maquina, localhost ou ip?

Tags: banco-de-dados, redes, ip

Tenho um website e banco de dados rodando na mesma maquina. E utilizo a seguinte string de conexão:

```
<add name="cs_name" connectionString="server=227.117.126.60;User Id=DBUser;database=my_main_db; password=t3st#;Convert Zero Datetime=True;SslMode=none" />
```

Estou apontando para o IP do servidor, porém poderia colorar `localhost:3306`

Existe uma diferença entre as duas abordagens quando se diz *VELOCIDADE*?

EDIT: pessoal desculpa eu quis exemplificar um IP mas acabou ficando entendido como IP local, o exemplo é só um IP aleatório, vou edita-lo para ficar de melhor entendimento.

O exemplo é a conexão da aplicação na mesma maquina que o banco de dados só que a uma aplicação chama o localhost e a outra o endereço IP publico da própria maquina.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 e localhost, caso de fato sejam a mesma máquina, não existe diferença de "velocidade", é apenas uma tradução do endereço da máquina. Não vai mudar absolutamente nada.

Comment: Caro @FilipeL.Constante não concordo que seja uma tradução, creio que quem resolve o endereço, mesmo que `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1` é o sistema operacional, independente de interface gráfica ou de existir adaptadores de rede. Pela lógica você poderia até fazer apontamentos diretamente via `/etc/hosts` (linux) ou `c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts` e qualquer endereço apontaria para outro. Claro que o sistema identifica as interfaces, mas ele quem "escolhe" o que é devolvido (dependendo de como foi configurado), então não creio que possamos chamar isso de "tradução"

Comment: Bom, então neste caso só recorrendo a literatura ou a um especialista na área p/ nos dar um norte preciso. :) É aquele negócio, vivendo e aprendendo.

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante sim, creio que o Bacco entenda disto, talvez o Anderson também, espero que o Leonardo espere mais respostas, só não tenho certeza se isso é ON-TOPIC, pq a primeira vista me pareceu OFF, mas preferi não votar pelo fechamento, vamos aguardar a comunidade ;)

Comment: Pessoal, eu editei a pergunta eu dei um exemplo que acabou sendo entendido de forma incorreta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na teoria, há diferença. Isso se dá pois `192.168.0.1`, o seu endereço local, vai até o roteador para ir até o servidor (que ironicamente, é o mesmo endereço do cliente).

Porém, o seu sistema operacional é inteligente o bastante para saber que ele não precisa de um intermediário para falar com ele mesmo.

Para tirar a prova, basta comparar o resultado do [`traceroute`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) para `192.168.x.x` e `127.0.0.1` (também conhecido como `localhost`).

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, pois é o endereço da máquina, não tem sentido ele sair p/ depois voltar para ele mesmo.

Comment: No caso de localhost e 127.0.0.1, sim. Mas 192.168.0.1 e 127.0.0.1, nem sempre.

Comment: posso estar falando besteira, mas é possivel que a máquina local resolve o endereço baixado do DHCP na interface de rede "associada" o que talvez "corte o caminho"  de ir e voltar, mas estou chutando, realmente de redes e ICMP eu não entendo. Creio que seria legal dar uma pesquisada sobre o assunto pare afirmar melhor (supondo que isso seja algo resolvido no sistema operacional)